# SQL: Joining a table with an unkown key that should be auto incremented

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Spring new web application(Java), and after having the user login (using username and password), I want to make the user able to add a new user, till then all is good. Each user have a primary Key iduser which autoincrimented (AI), and a foreign key idprofile. The table Profile contain informations about the user, and it's idprofile is the primary key (which have to be the same as the ipdrofile in User table).

As you may know, MySQL don't let you make more than one AI per table (MySQL 5 workbench as platform), and when my code add's an user, it has to add a profile in the same time, but with three fields that are unknown, which are iduser, idprofile (user table) and idprofile (profile table). As the ipdrofile can't be an AI, how can I manage to put the right key on it when saving the User and Profile (Adding) ?

[image]

Comment: If the system always adds a row to `profile` when it adds a row to `user`, why wouldn't you just combine those two tables into one? It's rare that you find a good reason for a one-to-one relationship in database design.

Comment: You are correct, yes ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You insert the `profile` first, returning the new profile id, then you insert the `user`, using the returned profile id, optionally returning the new user id if you need it.

You'll need to use these two methods to get the auto-generated key returned:

- [Connection.prepareStatement(String, String[])](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-)
- [Statement.getGeneratedKeys()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29)

Comment: getGeneratedKeys solved the problem, before I decide to remove such an useless one to one relation. Thank you